# How to add to inlinekeyboard button that open webapp

Tags: html, telegram, telegram-webhook

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot***/sendMessage?chat_id=*&text=Hi&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "Open WebApp", "web_app": {"url": "https://telegram.org/"}}]]}&parse_mode=html
```

i try this request, but i get this

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: BUTTON_TYPE_INVALID"}
```

i tried to find examples, but I didn't find anything